# Postgresql always reports hstore type not found in the database

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, hstore

I already got `hstore` extension installed. The version of postgresql is 9.4.4 and it was installed via homebrew.

```
# \dx
                       List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                   Description
---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore  | 1.3     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

But when I tried to execute `psycopg2.extras.register_hstore(con)`, it would report `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: hstore type not found in the database. please install it from your 'contrib/hstore.sql' file`.

The `hstore.sql` file locates at `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4/share/postgresql/extension`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Worth checking ... are you sure you are in the correct database when trying to call `register_hstore`?

Comment: @donkopotamus Trying to check it. I'm also doubting I'm not using the correct database or user.

Comment: @donkopotamus Seems I was using wrong user just now. Now it is normal. Please ignore this question. Thank you! :)